# In R how to extract the position or NULL entries in a lis

Tags: r, list

Using R how can I print the position of NULL entries in a list.

My list looks like this

```
list 
   name1    character[1]    xxxx
   name2    character[1]    xxxx
   name3    NULL            Pairlist of length 0
```

How can I simply just extract `3` as the positions of the list which are NULL.

I used `list2 <- list[sapply(list, is.null)]` to extract the whole entry of the NULL entries in the list, but I simply just want to print `3` for further work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `which`:

```r
l <- list(NULL, mtcars, NULL)
which(sapply(l, is.null))
#[1] 1 3
```

Answer (score 2):

`lengths` could work as well

```
 which(!lengths(list))
[1] 1 3
```